# Building RESTful API using R

Tags: r, rest, plumber

I am thinking about building a RESTful API using the programming language **R**, mainly to expose my machine learning model to the user in an API format. 
I know there are some options like export to PMML, PFA and use other languages to take care of the API part. However, I want to stick to the same programming language and was wondering if there is anything like Flask/Django/Springbook framework in R?

I took a look at [servr](https://github.com/yihui/servr)/[shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) but I really don't think RESTful is what they are designed for. Is there any better solution within **R** that is more easy to use?

Comment: https://github.com/trestletech/plumber

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have two options for you:

### [plumber](http://plumber.trestletech.com/)

> plumber allows you to create a REST API by decorating your existing R source
>   code with special comments.

A small example file:

```
# myfile.R

#* @get /mean
normalMean <- function(samples=10){
  data <- rnorm(samples)
  mean(data)
}

#* @post /sum
addTwo <- function(a, b){
  as.numeric(a) + as.numeric(b)
}
```

From the R command line:

```
> library(plumber)
> r <- plumb("myfile.R")  # Where 'myfile.R' is the location of the file shown above
> r$run(port=8000)
```

With this you would get results like this:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8000/mean"
 [-0.254]
$ curl "http://localhost:8000/mean?samples=10000"
 [-0.0038]
```

---

### [Jug](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jug/index.html)

> Jug is a small web development framework for R which relies heavily upon
>   the httpuv package. It’s main focus is to make building APIs for your
>   code as easy as possible. It is not supposed to be either an
>   especially performant nor an uber stable web framework. Other tools
>   (and languages) might be more suited for that. It’s main focus is to
>   easily allow you to create APIs for your R code. However, the
>   flexibility of Jug means that, in theory, you could built an extensive
>   web framework with it.

It very easy to learn and has a [nice vignette](http://bart6114.github.io/jug/articles/jug.html).

An Hello-World-example:

```
library(jug)

jug() %>%
  get("/", function(req, res, err){
    "Hello World!"
  }) %>%
  simple_error_handler_json() %>%
  serve_it()
```

Comment: can we secure this by oAuth?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide a list of special decorator comments used in Plumber?

Answer (score 7):

This is for those who want to have a comparion of API development with R - plumber, Rserve and rApache.

Basically concurrent requests are queued by `httpuv` in `plumber` so that it is not performant by itself. The author recommends multiple docker containers but it can be complicated as well as resource-demanding.

There are other tech eg `Rserve` and `rApache`. `Rserve` forks prosesses and it is possible to configure `rApache` to pre-fork so as to handle concurrent requests.

Comment: Referring to "the author" makes it seem like you didn't write those posts. Normally, not disclosing your affiliation with a recommendation like this would be considered spam; since your name is in the URLs, why phrase it like you aren't just linking people to your own work?

Comment: I wrote those posts while having the same question. The contents are long and don't fit here so that I added the links. Whether it's spam or not can be judged those who check the posts (and possibly who can identify who wrote them :)).

Comment: Cannot read links without logging in

Answer (score 6):

Adding [opencpu](/questions/tagged/opencpu) to this list of the answers:

Do check out [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org) by Jeroen Ooms.

Benefits:

1. **Simple and straightforward**: Any R package installed on the opencpu server is callable via http.
2. Just **focus on creating the R package** and opencpu will take care of the rest.
3. You can return a **relational table of results**, a **plot**, **single value** or even a **pointer** (aka a temporary session key) to an R object 
   [imagine a huge object/dataset that you can process/manipulate from other more limited platform ;) ]
4. **CI/CD** with your package hosted on Github.
5. If you are using the server version, opencpu is concurrent and async by design through leveraging of Nginx for **caching and load balancing**.
6. Use AppArmor to enforce **security** on Ubuntu. Or if you use fedora, you can set up public-private certificate authentication, thanks to Apache server at the backend. Thanks to rApache!
7. **The above are too complicated**: You can also start a single user session on your local machine using `opencpu::ocpu_start_app()` and serve your functions (downside is security)
8. Need an **user interface**? Simply create an UI using javascript, store it in the www folder of the R package and user can open it on their web browser and use your functions.

This post doesn't do opencpu justice. I would really recommend that you read his links at the top of [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org)

Have a playaround with https://cloud.opencpu.org/ocpu/test or https://www.opencpu.org/apps.html