# Is it possible to integrate an R algorithm within java code?

Tags: java, r, rest, web-services

I'd like to ask whether it is possible and whether it is simple to integrate R code into java.

I already have a java webservice. It exposes some REST api that call a java algorithm. However, the java algorithm is slower than R one. So, I'd like to substitute it with R algorithm, or build a new webservice from scratch using R. Is it possible to integrate the R code within java? What's the best way? Would you suggest me to use RServe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079580

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I have just edited again the question

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good idea if you use Rserve. Rserve would allow you to get your R code  variables and use them in your Java code.